# Using Vite for backend

Tags: node.js, vite, nodejs-server

We are using Vite for our frontend (inside SvelteKit) and it works nicely with creating SSR and frontend code.

I especially like the prebundling of 3rd party packages via esbuild.

Can someone tell me if it’s possible to use the Vite bundling pipeline for a backend-only project (nodejs server based on koa)?

Answer (score 23):

You can try [vite-plugin-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-node). This vite plugin supports multiple nodejs frameworks out of the box including koa. I have created a simple express app with it in typescript which worked fine for me. One downside is the plugin is fairly new and still in its early stage, so you may not want to use it in a serious production app.

Comment: Just FYI: that plugin seems to be unmaintained

Answer (score 16):

check out [vite-node](https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/tree/main/packages/vite-node)

it is a runtime for node that uses vite