# How do I bundle my Node.js code into a single file using Vite.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, vite

I am trying to bundle my Node.js server-side code (Koa app) into a single file which is what [Webpack produces](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/) when I use the `target` as `node`. This is what [`ncc - node.js compiler collection`](https://github.com/vercel/ncc) also achieves.

I am now using [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/) for my next project. I am able to bundle the code by using the SSR bundling feature provided by Vite. But I am not able to bundle third-party dependencies into this single file **excluding core/built-in node.js modules**. This is my Vite build script:

```js
import path from 'path';
import { build } from 'vite';
import builtinModules from 'builtin-modules';

async function main() {

  const result = await build({
    mode: 'production',
    appType: 'custom',
    root: path.join(process.cwd(), 'backend'),
    ssr: {
      format: 'esm',
      target: 'node',
      
      // By default Vite bundles everything except the one we pass via `external` array.
      external: builtinModules
    },
    build: {
      manifest: false,
      rollupOptions: {
        input: 'backend/main.mjs',
        output: {
          assetFileNames: 'bundle.js'
        }
      },
      outDir: '../dist/backend',
      ssr: true,
      emptyOutDir: true
    },
    plugins: [],
  });
}

main();
```

In the above code, `builtinModules` is simply the string array of all the core node.js modules:

```js
// builtinModules
[
  'assert',         'async_hooks',
  'buffer',         'child_process',
  'cluster',        'console',
  'constants',      'crypto',
  'dgram',          'diagnostics_channel',
  'dns',            'domain',
  'events',         'fs',
  'http',           'http2',
  'https',          'inspector',
  'module',         'net',
  'os',             'path',
  'perf_hooks',     'process',
  'punycode',       'querystring',
  'readline',       'repl',
  'stream',         'string_decoder',
  'timers',         'tls',
  'trace_events',   'tty',
  'url',            'util',
  'v8',             'vm',
  'worker_threads', 'zlib'
]
```

For my original source code:

```js
// main.mjs
import path from 'path';

import Koa from 'koa';

async function main() {
  console.log('Source folder', path.join(__dirname, 'src'));

  const app = new Koa();

  app.listen(3000);
}

main();
```

The produced output for the above Vite build configuration is:

```js
// bundle.js
import path from "path";
import Koa from "koa";
async function main() {
  console.log("Source folder", path.join(__dirname, "src"));
  const app = new Koa();
  app.listen(3e3);
}
main();
```

Ideally, I expected that it would bundle the `koa` package in the final output leaving behind only native `path` module. But that's not the case.

So, **how do I enable bundling of my entire backend/Node.js source code compile into single file leaving only core node.js modules as external as Node.js is the runtime for my code?** The vite server options also provide the [`noexternal`](https://vitejs.dev/config/ssr-options.html#ssr-noexternal) option but setting it to the `true` works only for `webworker` like runtime where **none** of the built-in node modules are available.

Comment: Out of interest: I can understand wanting to bundle FE code, but what's the rationale behind wanting to bundle BE code?

Comment: In the end nodejs server side code is always in memory, unless you specify so. I'm also not sure why you want to bundle it in one file.

Comment: @Andy Very valid question. Bundling server-code is extremely useful for serverless deployments. With this, the cold starts are avoided and `npm install` is not required when it gets deployed. The output of the CI/CD is just one file that is ready to be deployed anywhere the Node.js runtime is supported.

Comment: Maybe [https://github.com/axe-me/vite-plugin-node](https://github.com/axe-me/vite-plugin-node) based off [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69523560/using-vite-for-backend). Looks like it was updated a month ago. @HarshalPatil

Comment: The `vite-plugin-node` works and compiles successfully but doesn't achieve the required single file bundling. I guess I will have to rollout something on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Latest vite versions are using preloading you should tweak some rollup options to disable code splitting

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite' // 2.8.0
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react' // 1.0.7

export default defineConfig ({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        manualChunks: {}
      },
    },
  },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer from @svedova seems to work: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/7821#issuecomment-1382317338

vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

import packageJson from "./package.json";

const dependencies = Object.keys({
  ...packageJson.dependencies,
  ...packageJson.devDependencies,
});

const noExternal = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? dependencies : []

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    ssr: "./src/server-entry.ts",
    outDir: "./dist",
  },
  ssr: {
    noExternal
  },
});
```